# Does the Orlicz space associated to $e^{x^2}-1$ have a name?

Tags: pr.probability

The [Orlicz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz_space) associated to the convex function $e^{x^2}-1$ arises frequently in probabilistic problems (being in this space implies that a function has sub-Gaussian tails). Does this space have a more concise name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One often denotes $\psi_\alpha (x) = e^{x^\alpha} - 1$ for $\alpha \ge 1$, and the corresponding Orlicz space is $L_{\psi_\alpha}$.  An estimate on the $L_{\psi_\alpha}$ norm is also often referred to simply as a $\psi_\alpha$ estimate.  Of course, the case $\alpha = 2$ which you asked about is the one most often of interest.

One might also call this space $\exp(L^\alpha)$, in analogy with $L^p$ and $L\log L$, etc., but I've never seen this done.

Added: Here are a few references where the $\psi_\alpha$ and $L_{\psi_\alpha}$ notations are used:

1. Ledoux and Talagrand, [*Probability in Banach Spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-20212-4), p. 10 and chapter 11
2. Klartag, "[Uniform almost sub-gaussian estimates for linear
   functionals on convex sets](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Eklartagb/papers/psitwo.pdf)"
3. Giannopoulos, Pauoris, and Valettas, "[$\Psi_\alpha$-estimates for marginals of log-concave probability measures](https://web.archive.org/web/20110608172815/http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Egrigoris/log-concave-marginals.pdf)"